# What web platform is React VR intended to be built on?

Tags: react-360

I would like to begin developing with React VR, particularly with Google Cardboard, however, I am not sure if Google Cardboard is optimized for React VR. I am wondering if React VR is intended for more robust VR platforms like Daydream, Oculus, HTC Vive, etc.?

Comment: If your browser support the device, is it all what you need.

Answer (score 1):

React VR is meant to primarily work on top of WebVR so in theory it should work on any device that supports VR (Cardboard, Oculus, GearVR, etc).

Unfortunately support is still limited and WebVR isn't a fully developed standard yet. But you can get a React VR app running in stereoscopic 3d mode on most Android phones if you enable a flag in Chrome `chrome://flags#enable-webvr`. https://github.com/facebook/react-vr/issues/210

[image: React VR stereoscopic]

For Oculus headset + Caramel browser on Samsung GearVR headset + compatible phones stereoscopic 3d should work out of the box. https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/docs/vrbrowsers.html